# Display a text message if the shortcode is found?

Tags: functions, shortcode

For a few hours I try to show a message only if there is a gallery Picu, without success, an idea?

Have try this code, but not work:

```
    /**
 * galeries content
 */
function iconic_galeries_endpoint_content() {
    echo /* Template Name: Client Area */

get_header();
?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main">
        <section>
        <header class="entry-header">
                    <h1><?php _e( 'Photos gallery.', 'my-theme' ); ?></h1>
                </header>
            <article>

                <div class="entry-content">
                <?php
                $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

                if ( isset( $current_user->user_email ) ) {
                    echo '<p>' . sprintf( __( '%s, here is your client area', 'my-theme' ), $current_user->display_name ) . ':</p>';

                    if($output == '<li class="picu-status-' . get_post_status() . '"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>') echo '<div class="woocommerce-MyAccount-content">
    <div class="woocommerce-notices-wrapper"></div>
    <div class="woocommerce-Message woocommerce-Message--info woocommerce-info">
        Your gallery.   </div>

</div>';
else echo $output;

                    $output = do_shortcode( '[picu_list_collections email="' . $current_user->user_email . '"]' );

// the shortcode returns an empty <ul> tag, if there is no gallery 
// https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/picu/trunk/frontend/includes/picu-template-functions.php#L464

if($output == '<ul class="picu-collection-list"></ul>') echo '<div class="woocommerce-MyAccount-content">
    <div class="woocommerce-notices-wrapper"></div>
    <div class="woocommerce-Message woocommerce-Message--info woocommerce-info">
        There is no gallery.    </div>

</div>';
else echo $output;
                }

                ?>
                </div>
            </article>
            </section>
        </main>
    </div>

<?php
}
```

Thanks in advance
Nico

Comment: Where is `$output` first set? It looks like your are checking the value before it's set in your example code. Perhaps you need `do_shortcode()` at the beginning of your function.

Comment: How is that function being called? What's the problem you're trying to solve with this solution?

Comment: In fact, gallery user is displaying if user email is find. But if user have no gallery, shortcode is not displaying and I would put a message like: Sorry, you have no gallery for the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<article>

                <div class="entry-content">
                <?php
                $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

                if ( isset( $current_user->user_email ) ) {
                    echo '<p>' . sprintf( __( '%s, here is your client area', 'my-theme' ), $current_user->display_name ) . ':</p>';


                    $output = do_shortcode( '[picu_list_collections email="' . $current_user->user_email . '"]' );

                    // the shortcode returns an empty <ul> tag, if there is no gallery 
                   // https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/picu/trunk/frontend/includes/picu-template-functions.php#L464

                   if($output == '<ul class="picu-collection-list"></ul>') {
                        echo '<div class="woocommerce-MyAccount-content">
                                 <div class="woocommerce-notices-wrapper"></div>
                                 <div class="woocommerce-Message woocommerce-Message--info woocommerce-info">
                                   There is no gallery.
                                </div>
                             </div>';
                   }
                   else {
                       echo '<div class="woocommerce-MyAccount-content">
                                <div class="woocommerce-notices-wrapper"></div>
                                <div class="woocommerce-Message woocommerce-Message--info woocommerce-info">
                                    Your gallery.
                                </div>
                         </div>';
                       echo $output;
                  }
  }

                ?>
                </div>
            </article>
```

Comment: once again thank you, you have just, very very thanks !!